# Smart UV project fail 100's of squares

Tags: uv

I am trying to unwrap the UV map with smart uv project but it keeps creating either 100's of triangles or tilted squares ? pretty much unusable ... pictures:
before smart uv projection:
[image]

and after:

[image]

i've applied scale and rotations before hand as well so that isn't the issue ....
im pretty new to blender and im guessing this isn't right?

Comment: Well, the UV map before was unsusable too as it had all kinds overlapping faces. What you've done is you have all leaves in one mesh. Since the leaves are not connected, each gets its own UV island... so there are lots of UV island to be placed in that space, and you've set a margin of 0.01, which makes it necessary to have them very small to fit all in that area with lots of space between them. Usually all leaves would be one single quad and you choose _Reset_ for unwrapping, which places them all on top each other filling the whole UV grid. This way all leaves would have the same UV.

Comment: And this could be used in a single material, so that all leaves share the same leaf texture or whatever. The other way would be you create a single leaf which can have more faces in the mesh so that you could slightly deform it etc., create one UV map for this coherent mesh, and instance this where those placeholder leaves are. By the way, this is not a "Smart UV project fail", it's just a misunderstanding of how _Smart UV Project_ really works.